# build public key PEM file with existing modulus and exponent in php with openssl library

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, rsa

I have public's key's modulus and exponent. Can I generate the public key with openssl api in php ? I've read the http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php but there seems no function that archive that.

If openssl cannot do it(build public key with modulus and exponent), can i use any any option in php to do that?

Comment: I am not a PHP expert. But this approach is not good. It is generally advisable to change the public key and private key after certain period of the time. Generally certificate has validity period. If you key's modulus and exponent, you have public key (this is what RSA public key means). If you need a certificate, you need private key to generate CSR.

Answer (score 2):

Using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->loadKey( array ('e'=>new Math_BigInteger('65537'), 'n'=>new Math_BigInteger('11944573237954459805614520005393273287786384679965238498958830373752732874397055'.
'98832111464872863171681422024469555089029360351247093972211786644957214280299847'.
'26868375359168203283442617134197706515425366188396513684446494070223079865755643'.
'116690165578452542158755074958452695530623055205290232290667934914919')) );

echo $rsa;
```

The output is as follows:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVx
wTCpvKe4eCZ0FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFnc
CzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0T
p0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

If your modulus and exponent came from a RSA key in XML format or you are retrieving the key from a [JWKS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) endpoint you can use the following code:

```php
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$n = "6R-qAvAPQNrx8I_Q7GmQE4zpKFBpKMM38yeFE797v9eLBdXr9JIW5PBuBqjkmzMug3MUvl4FM6_nU0SCMLDMSY_zGIt5xlmFF5iqRb8elTZ_bLe6bp_1cZncadl4vzRdi6jQE_aIZX_9CWypO4su-kNj6DVCh5wldbGZej0c-1sKCgkJF12hiAqQPxaIA4hDgDCFiCRWSPzxHRuS-aXV0h3DIhn84lCkzrBqWea-nS03z0k2ohmuNsTd0yIPz_s-R2TkE-lUaKVtKGqsRPL3GKzQJO4TUzYmqHkN8XyNkmvBaitWreiZjyX79qTJ46SNX55gzVAfWqevpJc0RezVsQ==";
$e = "AQAB";

// Convert Base64 uri-safe variant to default (needed for JWKS)
$n = strtr($n, '-_', '+/');

$rsa = new RSA();

$key = "<RSAKeyPair>"
        . "<Modulus>" . $n . "</Modulus>"
        . "<Exponent>" . $e . "</Exponent>"
        . "</RSAKeyPair>";

$rsa->loadKey($key, RSA::PUBLIC_FORMAT_XML);

echo $rsa;
```